# Paperclip's Post Processing starts before virtual attributes get values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, before-filter

I'm using Paperclip gem in my new project for storing images. There's also simple custom Paperclip processor I wrote to crop images according to crop parameters, stored in my model's virtual attributes.

So client transfers form with model's actual db fields and crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, crop_h attributes, controller creates new instance based on "params" --- that's going well -- I checked it, but then some weird things are taking place.

here's my model:

```
class Jewel < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items
belongs_to :material

******* some code *********

before_save :debugmeBS

validates :category_id, :presence => true

attr_accessor   :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
attr_accessible :name, :category_id, :price, :crop_x, :crop_y, 
:crop_w, :crop_h, :image

after_update :reprocess_image, :if => :need_to_crop?

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :full => "900x", :smallthumb => "80x80>" }, 
:processors => [:cropper, :thumbnail]

before_post_process :debugmePP

def need_to_crop?
    # debugger
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? &&!crop_w.blank? &&!crop_h.blank?
end

private 
    def debugmeBS
        debugger
        x=2

    end

    def debugmePP
        debugger
        x=3

    end
 end
```

Debugger placed in my custom processor shows that crop_x, crop_y and others virtual attributes are blank (by invoking "need_to_crop?" method) meanwhile other not-virtual ones are set properly. To track-down error I placed two "before_"-events: before_save and Paperclip's before_post_process. Turns out that before_post_process is invoked before before_save and on the moment all my "crop_" attributes are nil, but on the moment of before_save fire, those are properly set up. 
 so the question is why? and how to set my virtual attributes to be accessed by Paperclip processor? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit the same thing as well.  Looking at the code for Paperclip (see callbacks.rb, attachment.rb, and paperclip.rb under lib/paperclip/), it seems the before_post_process and before__post_process callbacks are invoked when the file is assigned to the  attribute.  My guess is that this is happening before the other attributes on the model are set.

UPDATE:
I asked on the GitHub Issues for the Paperclip project, and what I wrote above was confirmed. The timing of the processing does depend on when the  attribute is assigned.  Since attributes are assigned alphabetically, depending on the name of the , it can be assigned before any of the other attributes.

For a workaround, you can do:

```
def create
  avatar = params[:resource].delete(:avatar)
  resource = Resource.new(params[:resource]
  resource.avatar = avatar
  resource save
end
```

source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1279

Comment: hack , but nice hack :)